# JavaScript loop in a simple quiz

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, firebug

Simple school quiz-project based on JavaScript, these are the files the whole quiz consists of:

- **Quiz.html:** http://www.rapidimg.org/server/files/50ab9c326115cKAUf6S.png
- **Quiz_questions.js:** http://www.rapidimg.org/server/files/50ace68ad21d9GPIha7.png (random letters behind the images to show it does load the answers)
- **Quiz_functions.js:** This is where it's mainly about, see below.
- **Output:** http://www.rapidimg.org/server/files/50ace6c57c01aTsZpMk.png (This is correct!)

It loads one question with the corresponding answers, so that works fine. (See the Output above). Now as soon as I click "Next Question" by selecting or not selecting an answer, two different things happen.

**Not selected an answer:** http://www.rapidimg.org/server/files/50ace9123bce6TzoiqL.png - loads Question 2 + answers but puts the page in an infinite loading state. When I click another answer and hit "Next Question", Firebug shows: http://www.rapidimg.org/server/files/50ace9a08b88aqLFZ1K.png

**Selected an answer:** http://www.rapidimg.org/server/files/50acea1422aed6gZkcL.png - loads Question 3 + answers (???) but also puts the page at infinite load. Same error as above when clicking an answer + "Next Question" button: http://www.rapidimg.org/server/files/50acea4e4bc3cLn8g2U.png

**Here's the code of "quiz_functions.js" where this is realised:**

```
var useranswers = new Array();
var imgArray = new Array();
var answered = 0;
var currentQuestion = 0;


function renderQuizViaArray() 
{
    document.write('<h1>' + questions[currentQuestion] + '</h1>');

    for(i=0, j=choices[currentQuestion].length; i < j; i++)
    {
        document.writeln('<input type="radio" name="answer_' + currentQuestion + '" value="1" id="answer_' + currentQuestion + '_' + i + '" class="question_' + currentQuestion + '" onclick="submitAnswer(' + currentQuestion + ', this, \'question_' + currentQuestion + '\', \'label_' + currentQuestion + '_' + i + '\')" /><label id="label_' + currentQuestion + '_' + i + '" for="answer_' + currentQuestion + '_' + i + '"> ' + choices[currentQuestion][i] + '</label><br />');
    }

        document.write('<input type="submit" value="Next Question" onclick="nextQuestion()" />');
}

function nextQuestion()
{
    currentQuestion++;
    renderQuizViaArray();
}

function submitAnswer(questionId, obj, classId, labelId) 
{
  useranswers[questionId] = obj.value;
  document.getElementById(labelId).style.fontWeight = "bold";
  disableQuestion(classId);
  answered++;
}

function disableQuestion(classId) 
{
  var alltags = document.all? document.all : document.getElementsByTagName("*")
  for (i = 0; i < alltags.length; i++) 
  {
    if (alltags[i].className == classId) 
    {
      alltags[i].disabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```